# Call OnClick with ImageView in other layout file

Tags: java, android

I have one Activity, which is `MainActivity` with a `NavigationDrawer`. So, when I click on my first item in my `NavigationDrawer`, I open a `Fragment` in `MainActivity`. In this `Fragment`, I inflate a layout with an `ImageView`. But when I click the `ImageView`, it does not work. Can you explain me why that's not work if it's possible? Thanks.

Here's the `onClick` implementation in my `Fragment`.

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stream, container, false);

    mItemsContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container_items);
    mItemsContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    //Pub perso
    View rootViewx = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_item, container, false);
    ImageView imgFavorite = rootViewx.findViewById(R.id.adviewperso);
    imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String url = "MYURL";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Pub appuyé !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //TEST2
    CardView cardtest = rootViewx.findViewById(R.id.adCard);
    cardtest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String url = "MYURL";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Pub appuyé !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    //TEST2
    //Fin pub perso


    mMessage = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.message);

    mFabButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
    mFabButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    itemsAdapter.setOnMoreButtonClickListener(new AdvancedItemListAdapter.OnItemMenuButtonClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, Item obj, int actionId, int position) {

            switch (actionId) {

                case R.id.action_repost: {

                    if (obj.getFromUserId() != App.getInstance().getId()) {

                        if (obj.getRePostFromUserId() != App.getInstance().getId()) {

                            repost(position);

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.msg_not_make_repost), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.msg_not_make_repost), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    break;
                }

                case R.id.action_share: {

                    onPostShare(position);

                    break;
                }

                case R.id.action_report: {

                    report(position);

                    break;
                }

                case R.id.action_remove: {

                    remove(position);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    final GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            if(dy > 0) {

                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!loadingMore) {

                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount && (viewMore) && !(mItemsContainer.isRefreshing())) {

                        loadingMore = true;
                        Log.e("...", "Last Item Wow !");

                        getItems();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mFabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewItemActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, STREAM_NEW_POST);
        }
    });

    if (itemsAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.label_empty_list).toString());

    } else {

        hideMessage();
    }

    if (!restore) {

        showMessage(getText(R.string.msg_loading_2).toString());

        getItems();
    }

    return rootView;

}
```

And the layout containing `adviewperso` looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#F5F5F5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/adCard"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:tint="@color/sponsored"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_sponsored"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/adTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_sponsored"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                    android:textColor="@color/sponsored"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:minHeight="64dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/adviewperso"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ads:srcCompat="@drawable/pub" />

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    ads:adSize="320x150">
                </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

I do not have any errors when I compile or when I run my app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things. Make the `ImageView` clickable from the layout and I think the `AdView` is overlapping the `ImageView` which is making it not clickable.

So the views under the `RelativeLayout` should look like the following.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="64dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adviewperso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        ads:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adviewperso"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        ads:adSize="320x150"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**

You are returning `rootView` from your `onCreateView`. You cannot inflate multiple layouts in a single `Fragment`. So the layout you are inflating using `View rootViewx = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_item, container, false);` will not have any effect if you are not returning the same layout from `onCreateView`.

I hope you have the `ImageView` in your `fragment_stream` layout or it includes the `ad_item` layout. So if the `ad_item` layout is included in your `fragment_stream` layout, then you can get the view id associated with the layout easily without having inflating it separately.

If you have two `Fragment`, then you need two separate `Fragment` class where you inflate `ad_item` and `fragment_stream` separately. And then, you join them together using another `Fragment` as a holder of these two fragments.

Comment: Thanks. I have allready try to delete my `Admob Banner`. That's didn't change nothing. I've try to make `clickable` my `ImageView`. That's not work. But thanks for try to help me

Comment: You have set `android:clickable="true"` in your `ImageView` right?

Comment: Yes, like your exemple

Comment: I saw you have updated your question with the `onCreateView`. Please post the full `onCreateView` as I think the `onCreateView` function has some problem.

Comment: Why are you inflating multiple views - `rootView` and `rootViewX`? Which view you are returning from your `onCreateView`?

Comment: Because i use `2 fragments`. The `first fragment is for Data`. `The second is for advert`. I call the second fragment, after the first `Data` in` Fragment 1`. After my `Advert Fragment`, we have` Data 2, Data 3, Data 4, ...`

Comment: An exemple in picture (for why i have 2 fragments) : [link]https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/13/5/1522440559-exemple.png